# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found PHP. Win7 - Apache - PHP

Tags: php, windows, com

```
$myapp = new COM("word.application");
// returns a fatal error: "Class 'COM' not found in c:/www/comConnector.php"

shell_exec("whoami");
//returns "NT authority/system"
```

### My system setup

- Win7 Pro
- Apache Server version: Apache/2.2.23 (Win32)
- PHP

> PHP 5.3.16 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2012 20:06:57)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add COM support in php.ini:

```
 [COM_DOT_NET]
     extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Comment: Thanks, Woks fine ! Ohh Radu Bompa... Radu Bompa :-)

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Maybe you can mark the question as answered :)

Comment: @Disquamovible Please accept this answer , in case this answers your query. regards

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using PHP 5.3.16, make sure that you are pointing to the global namespace:

```
$myapp = new \COM("word.application");
```

Even though your PHP file might be in global namespace already, but it's a good practice.