# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in C:\Program Files\

Tags: php

I have a big problem. i have this error

```
"Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\eu\include\general.php on line 2768"
```

and when I go to that line I see this:

```
" if (PHP_OS=='WINNT')
{
$filesystem=new COM('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
$file=$filesystem->GetFile($path);
return $file->Size();........"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!
Adi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found PHP. Win7 - Apache - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781145/fatal-error-class-com-not-found-php-win7-apache-php)

Answer (score 2):

In `php.ini` uncomment line: `;extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` (remove `;`) and restart server. Because it's extension for php.

By the way, in your version this line may be missing. There's a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62623).

Answer (score 0):

add
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
on php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Open php.ini with a note editor (ctrl+F) search for `Dynamic Extensions` after that add `extension=com_dotnet`