# Class 'COM' not found in php 5.5.11

Tags: php, nginx

I have no Idea, why i see this,
I am using php 5.5.11 (php-cgi.exe) , windows 7 ultimate x86, nginx 1.5.10
According to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php) I don't need php_com_dotnet.dll to enable my php.ini.

```
Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in pertama._.php on line 6
```

in pertama._.php i have,

```
function get_server_load() {
    if (stristr(PHP_OS, 'win')) {
        $wmi = new COM("Winmgmts://");
        $server = $wmi->execquery("SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_Processor");
        $cpu_num = 0;
        $load_total = 0;
        foreach($server as $cpu){
            $cpu_num++;
            $load_total += $cpu->loadpercentage;
        }
        $load = round($load_total/$cpu_num);
    } else {
        $sys_load = sys_getloadavg();
        $load = $sys_load[0];
    }
    return (int) $load;
}
```

Comment: It's obvious that class `COM` is not available to use so `$wmi = new COM("Winmgmts://");` raised the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found PHP. Win7 - Apache - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781145/fatal-error-class-com-not-found-php-win7-apache-php)

Comment: Did you enable `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` in `php.ini` ?

Comment: This is not a duplication. he has PHP 5.3.16 that need to enable an extension to activate that. but in mu case it is php 5.5.11

Comment: [Could be helpful](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-wmi-dig-deep-windows-php/).

Comment: @MasumNishat Either way, there are multiple questions on this topic.  [You should search online before asking questions](http://google.com).  Then if a question seems similar, talk about it in your question and how it does not answer your question.

Comment: for php 5.5 ts x86 version i can not fiend php_com_dotnet.dll extension in google

Comment: last 1hrs i am trying this to solve. but i cannot !!

Comment: Just read the answer from the question that I linked to.

Comment: If you do a phpinfo() - do you have com_dotnet/COM enabled ?

Comment: `--enable-com-dotnet=shared` i have got this in my phpinfo();

Comment: Shared means dll is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution after all.

for php 5.5 you don't need to have any `php_com_dotnet.dll` in your `ext` directory.Just add

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

in your php.ini this will solve every problem.